# matplotlib line chart in Django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, charts

I´m trying to create a line chart with n lines, n is variable. I´m using matplotlib and Django 1.7 with python 2.7.

And I already can make a one line chart, but when I try to make 2, or more it doesn´t work. The chart generated has only one of the values passed. I´m using Django Query searchs in the model as values to create the chart, I choose the itens of the chart through a check list make in another view that alread works, I´ve tested.

Here it is my function:

```
def chart(request): 
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
    if 'checks[]' in request.GET and request.GET['checks[]']:
        #getting id's of selected tags
        chosen = request.GET.getlist('checks[]')
        tags = Tag.objects.filter(id__in = chosen)
        tagIds = [];
        for tag in tags:
            tagIds.append(tag.id)
        values = Values.objects.filter(tag__in = tagIds)
        fig=Figure()
        ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
        y=[]
        x=[]
        for value in values:
            y.append(value.value)
            x.append(value.datetime)
        ax.plot_date(x, y, '-')
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
        fig.autofmt_xdate()
        canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
        response=HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
        canvas.print_png(response)
        return response
```

Comment: What do you mean by "try to make two" and "does not work". Two lines in one subplot? I only see one `plt.plot_date()` in the code you provided.

Comment: Yes, But to make a multiple line chart I don´t need only to add multiple lists? 2 to each line chart? I take this two examples to make this code  [figure canvas example](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Django.html) [pyplot example](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#pyplot-tutorial)

Comment: Create two sets of data and call `ax.plot_date()` once for each.

Comment: @NilsWerner This make to me an error "ordinal must be >= 1". That was generated at "fig.autofmt_xdate() "

Comment: @Nathan that means you have bad date data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I was looking for the values on the list. I thought the list was a list of lists, each one of one Tag´s value. But actually was a whole list for all Tags.  So the part of get the values are now like this. It worked thx.

```
    #getting all values of all selected tags
    for tag in tags:
        #values of one tag
        values = Values.objects.filter(tag = tag.id)
        x = []
        y = []
        #all values of one tag
        for value in values:
            y.append(value.value)
            x.append(value.datetime)
            #ax.plot_date(value.value, value.datetime, '-')
        ax.plot_date(x, y, '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ax.plot_date()` on each dataset, e.g.

```
for offset in [0, 100]:
    y=[]
    x=[]
    for value in values:
        y.append(value.value + offset)
        x.append(value.datetime)
    ax.plot_date(x, y, '-')
```

draws two lines, one with a 100 units offset.

Comment: I think I get the idea, but I don´t wanna make 2 line chart, and not with the same data. I wanna make multiple line charts, one,two,three..... with the same function. And each one of the line is one of the query set of Django, each line is one and unique data.